# scripting getfeatureinfo for multiple wms layers

Tags: javascript, wms, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo

I am not really a programmer and I'm trying to create a webservice. I copy and pasted some script examples which made my script what it is now. I have multiple wms layers, but want to show different info in the infowindow for each wms. So I thought this can be done by an if-then-else statement. First, I created the getfeatureinfo variable including the layers which need to have information shown.

```
var control_identify = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    title : 'Klik op een lijn voor informatie',
    layers : [ AmiceHerkomst, AmiceVerwerking ],
    queryVisible : true,
    infoFormat : 'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
    vendorParams: {
        buffer: 5  // geoserver buffer in pixels
    },
    eventListeners : {
        getfeatureinfo : function(event){
            showInfo(event);
        }
    }
});

control_identify.events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
```

then I create the showinfo function. Here I want to make an if-then-else for each wms layer I have. Something in the line of if(evt.features.length != 0) and layer = AmiceHerkomst { followed by the attributes I want from that layer. For the next layer I add at the end else if (evt.features.length != 0) and layer = AmiceVerwerking { with the attributes I want for this layer and so on. Scripting like I said above will give an error, but I think something like this should be possible?

```
function showInfo(evt) {
    var f = 0;
    var temstr = "";
    if(evt.features.length != 0){
        for (f = 0; f <= evt.features.length - 1; f++) {

            temstr = temstr + "<table>";
            for ( var key in evt.features[f].attributes) {
                temstr += "<tr>";

                switch (key){
                case 'afvalstroo':
                    temstr += "<td width= 71px>Afvalstroom</td><td>"
                    + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                    break;
                case 'plaatsloca':
                    temstr += "<td width= 71px>Plaatsnaam</td><td>"
                    + evt.features[f].attributes[key] + "</td>";
                    break;

                default:
                };
                temstr += "</tr>";
            }
            temstr = temstr + "</table>";
        };
        log("<b>Informatie</b><br/>" + temstr, true);
    } else {
        log("<b>Informatie</b><br/>" + "Niets gevonden op deze locatie", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to response format JSON and iterate through the response-features:

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
             infoFormat : 'application/json',
             drillDown: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {

                    popuphtml="";

                    retrieved_response=JSON.parse(event.text);
                    retrieved_objects=retrieved_response.features;
                    if(retrieved_objects.length>0)
                    {


                    for(var i=0;i<retrieved_objects.length;i++)
                    {
                    loop_layer_id=retrieved_objects[i].id;
                    loop_layer_id = loop_layer_id.substring(0,loop_layer_id.indexOf("."));
                    //console.log(loop_layer_id);
                    if(loop_layer_id=="tasmania_state_boundaries")
                    {
                    popuphtml=popuphtml+"<br />"+loop_layer_id+"<br />STATE: "+retrieved_objects[i].properties.STATE+"<br />";
                    }
                    else if(loop_layer_id=="tasmania_roads")
                    {
                    popuphtml=popuphtml+"<br />"+loop_layer_id+"<br />TYPE: "+retrieved_objects[i].properties.TYPE+"<br />";
                    }
                    else if(loop_layer_id=="tasmania_water_bodies")
                    {
                    popuphtml=popuphtml+"<br />"+loop_layer_id+"<br />WaterTYPE: "+retrieved_objects[i].properties.WATER_TYPE+"<br />";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    popuphtml=popuphtml+"<br />other content"+"<br />";
                    }

                    }
                    //console.log(popuphtml);
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken", 
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                       popuphtml 
                        ,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    alert("no response...");
                    }



                }
            }
        });
        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();
```

[image]